# Illegal Instruction error when verifying Anaconda/Miniconda Install

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to install Anaconda or Miniconda, whichever one I can get to work. I am running on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 64-bit Ubuntu Server. After following the instructions on Anaconda's website to install and verify the installation, I get `Illegal Argument (core dumped)` when using command `conda list` or most other commands like `conda install`. `conda --version` works and tells me I have version 4.10.1. Here are the exact commands I used to install and verify 1.  `wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-aarch64.sh`
2. `bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-aarch64.sh` 3. `nano ~/.bashrc` 4. Added this to the bashrc file `export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` 5. `source ~/.bashrc` Both Miniconda and Anaconda result in the same error for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing similar issue(Illegal instruction) in setting up miniconda 4.10.1 and 4.10.3(this is latest miniconda version as on today) however was able to install 4.9.2 on raspberry pi os 64 bit without any issue. I guess 4.9.2 version should work for 64 bit ubuntu server as well.

Link to miniconda version that I was able to install on my pi 4, aarch64 is
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh

In case you want to try out other version, check this repository

https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/

Comment: nice solution, but is only temporary solution, I get a problem when conda install tweepy and other library in python

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Using version 4.9.2 helped at first, but once I wanted to install something using pip, I got again the illegal instruction error.

For me the community version of miniconda worked like a charm on raspberry4!

[Miniforge3](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge)

Answer (score -1):

Miniforge3 worked on my pi 3b+

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).